# SessionFactory giving NullPointerException on Hibernate5 Spring 4.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I've got a Java Config class called `PersistenceJPAConfig` in which I configure the stuff related to persistence (session factory, transactions, etc), 
a `UserService` class that communicates with the `UserDAO` to get all users from the database using a method from the SessionFactory.

Everything seems beautifully functional in theory. However, when I try to get these users : a "NullPointerException" is thrown.

Does anyone have a clue?

**Config class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {


@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());

    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.br.modelar.Modelar.model").addProperties(additionalProperties());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(){

    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean manager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    JpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

    manager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    manager.setPackagesToScan("com.br.modelar.Modelar.model");
    manager.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    manager.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return manager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/modelar_test");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("hibernate.query.factory_class","org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
            "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}

}
```

**UserService class**

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements ServiceInterface<User, Integer>{

private HibernateUserDAO userDAO;

public UserService() {
    userDAO = new HibernateUserDAO();
}
@Override
public List<User> getAll() {

    return userDAO.getAll();
}
}
```

**DAO class**

```
@Repository
public class HibernateUserDAO implements DAOInterface<User, Integer>{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<User> getAll() {

    List<User> users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT FROM mduser").list();

    return users;
}
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.br.modelar.Modelar.dao.HibernateUserDAO.getAll(HibernateUserDAO.java:50)
com.br.modelar.Modelar.service.UserService.getAll(UserService.java:44)
com.br.modelar.Modelar.controller.AdminController.viewUsers(AdminController.java:69)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Admin Controller - Call to getAll()**

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/view_users")
public ModelAndView viewUsers() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("admin/show_users");
    //UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();

    //List<User> users = dao.getAll();

    UserService service = new UserService();
    List<User> users = service.getAll();

    model.addObject("users", users);
    return model;
}
}
```

Comment: what's the error/stacktrace ?

Comment: sorry, mate haha. I forgot to put the stack trace. I've updated =D thanks

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the `UserDao` don't do that use `@Autowired` to get the spring configured instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you =D this and some other problems ben75 pointed out helped to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session.createQuery(query) requires a valid HQL query string. I'm not HQL expert, but I think that `"SELECT FROM mduser"` is just wrong. Try this :

```
List<User> users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM mduser").list();
```

---

HibernateUserDAO is probably not scanned by Spring. Be sure that Spring is scanning package with your DAO. (additionally posting the code were you call `getAll()` would be useful)

---

ok... after your last edit, the problems are :

```
UserService service = new UserService();
```

and

```
private HibernateUserDAO userDAO;
```

UserService is a bean managed by Spring : you cannot create it like that. You must inject it with something like :

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
```

When you use injection (instead of explicit instanciation) the object is created by Spring and spring take care to initialize it properly (by injecting a userDAO in your case - see next point).

**Next point**

```
private HibernateUserDAO userDAO;
```

userDao is not annotated : Spring won't do anything with that field and that's a problem. You must add an annotation:

```
@Autowired
private HibernateUserDAO userDAO;
public UserService() {
    //nothing here
}
```

As a general rule : never instantiate a bean yourself: Spring do it for you !
(any class annotated with @Repository, @Service, @Component ... -and there are more- is a bean.)

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks for pointing this out. =D The exception is occurring at "sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()". sessionFactory is null when it should not be and I don't know why haha

Comment: Hi, I added the annotation @ComponentScan passing as backPackages the root package where all my Java files are.  However, it didn't work as well. There is an update in the question with you suggestion.

Comment: Much thanks @ben75 =D that was the problem! I faced some issues afterwards regarding the interface I was using, but I did some research and I found the solution. Thank you, again